# How to request for permission: READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE?

Tags: android, permissions

How can I request for permission "android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"? I know that starting from Android 10, third-party apps installed from the Google Play Store cannot declare privileged permissions.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#data-ids

However my app will not be distributet with Google Play Store. I will share the apk file and users will install aplication manually.

I have declared permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
```

I'm also trying to request it as any regular permission:

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), "android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE") != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{"android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"},123);
        }
```

But nothing is happening. I'm not being prompted to grant this permission. No alert dialog is being presented. How can I request for this permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant put this permission for android 10 version. You could change your targetSdkVersion to below 29

> Android 10 changes the permissions for device identifiers so that all device identifiers are now protected by the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission.The READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission is only granted to apps signed with the platform key and privileged system apps.

reference:

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/device-identifiers

Comment: So there is no way for getting this permission? Even if I'm sideloading my APK?

Comment: No,, only system apps have this permission. I had same problem in my project. I made a request to OEM of project.

Comment: What to do when i need that permission in Android 10 ?

Comment: No meu caso, eu não preciso - botei por outro motivo e só tava dando erro. Retirei e bombou!

Comment: I am in the scenario now, I am updating my target SDK to 29 and I am giving APK directly to users. How can I use getDeviceIed()? I am getting securityExecption after I update SDK to 29.

Comment: Hello, you can check this link. I must to use getMeid

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getDeviceId(int)